# Sort div's using data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to sort the nested div by the last name (after space) using the data attribute.

The div hierarchy as follows:

```js
var oop = $('.wrap').sort(function(a, b) {
  return String.prototype.localeCompare.call(
    $(a).data('name').split(' ').pop().trim().toLowerCase(), 
    $(b).data('name').split(' ').pop().trim().toLowerCase()
  );
});
$('.speakers-row').html(oop);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="speakers-row">
  <div class="wrap" data-name="Aric Zer">
    11
  </div>
  <div class="wrap" data-name="Mike Aer">
    22
  </div>
  <div class="wrap" data-name="Ryan Xer">
    33
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't you sort the data before building the page? If the name data is dynamic, this is the wrong way to sort it

Comment: Looks like it works as designed. I created a snippet and it sorts in Aer, Xer, Zer

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Actually, I am getting the speaker name as **data-name** attribute from backend and trying to sort the div using jQuery.

Comment: agree with @mplungjan when you add the last name in DIV's content, you will see it. Note I had to replace the space for `Xer` which did not gave me same result during test

Comment: `It's caused (by a typo) or problem that can no longer be reproduced. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers.`

Comment: @el-teedee Which space?

Comment: @el-teedee was right. I fixed it by placing a **trim()** function before the **split(' ')**. It works!

Comment: What space? There is no space in your data-name in the above code that will be handled by a trim BEFORE the split

Comment: i deleted my answer, question can be closed now